# How to replace words in an array's value with another

Tags: php, arrays

```
    <?php
$array1 = array(
                1 => "Lorem ipsum w1 lorem ipsum",
                2 => "Lorem ipsum w1 lorem ipsum",
                3 => "Lorem ipsum w1 lorem w1 ipsum",
                4 => "Lorem ipsum w1 lorem ipsum",
                5 => "Lorem ipsum w1 lorem ipsum",
                );
?>
```

How can I replace the word "w1" with another word "w2"  and then generate a new array like

```
    <?php
    $array1 = array(
                1 => "Lorem ipsum w2 lorem ipsum",
                2 => "Lorem ipsum w2 lorem ipsum",
                3 => "Lorem ipsum w2 lorem w2 ipsum",
                4 => "Lorem ipsum w2 lorem ipsum",
                5 => "Lorem ipsum w2 lorem ipsum",
                );
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$res = array();
foeach($array1 as $key=>$val){
  $res[$key]   = str_replace("W1","W2",$val);
}

print_r($res);
```

Refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for details about str_replace

Comment: you could skip the $res[$key] part and just use $val if your foreach is $key => &$val.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with either [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) depending on how much functionality you need.

Both of these functions accept an array as their `$subject` argument, so it could be as simple as

```
$array1 = array(...); // strings with "w1"
$array1 = str_replace('w1', 'w2', $array1);
```

Comment: I would not recommend `preg_replace` for a simple task like this.

Comment: @DainisAbols: What is the simple task exactly? Obviously `"w1"` => `"w2"` is just an example. Perhaps in real life the regex `\bw1\b` would be needed?